# Error using Jquery Sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

```
<div>
<ul id="sortable">
</ul></div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // Your code here
        $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
        $('#sortable').sortable( "disable" );
        $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
    });

</script>
```

This is the code I currently have in my html. Now the  list would be updated dynamically after the user fills in couple of forms. I append the "li"s to the ul using the innerhtml function.
And then call:

```
$('#sortable').sortable( "refresh" );
$('#sortable').sortable( "enable" );
```

to enable the jquery sorting but for some reason its not working.
When I use the above two functions in a javascript function, Im getting the error "sortable is not a function.
But if I dont use it and don't disable the sortable in the first place, nothing happens!
Any help would be appreciated
Thanks!!!

Comment: Did you import the jQuery UI script with the Sortable module ?

Comment: Yes I did import it, it worked fine when I used a static ul

Comment: You saw you have to check "sortable" when building the UI js ?

Comment: Oh I got it, I have written the initial function right after the import statements. I have a long list of imports and as a result by the time the first statement was executed, the import wasnt done completely.

Comment: jsfiddle for us may be usefull http://jsfiddle.net/Mutmatt/8nb7B/

Answer (score 1):

here is the error

```
<div>
<ul id="sortable"
</ul></div>       ^------missing the closing ">"
```

should be

```
<div>
<ul id="sortable">
</ul></div>
```

and as the The [@nbrooks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/803925/nbrooks) error is "sortable is not a function", doesn't seem to be a result of malformed HTML (although that is a problem)

Comment: Im sorry I didnt get you.
If it's about the id, Jquery official website has the same bit of code

Comment: The error is "sortable is not a function", doesn't seem to be a result of malformed HTML (although that is a problem)

Answer (score 0):

The "sortable is not a function" error message points without ambiguity towards a Sortable library import problem :

- jQuery UI not imported
- "Sortable" not checked when building the UI library
- your code executed before the document is ready